# Preencher select multiple com dados armazenados no banco

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde a todos.

Preciso de uma orientação de vocês com relação a select multiple.

Eu tenho o select abaixo:

```
<select class="form-control" id="dias_semana" multiple name="diasDaSemana[]" required>
<option value="">Selecione...</option>
<option value="Domingo">Domingo</option>
<option value="Segunda">Segunda-Feira</option>
<option value="Terca">Terça-Feira</option>
<option value="Quarta">Quarta-Feira</option>
<option value="Quinta">Quinta-Feira</option>
<option value="Sexta">Sexta-Feira</option>
<option value="Sabado">Sábado</option>
</select>
```

Através do select acima estou conseguindo selecionar mais de uma opção e envia para o banco.

Minha dificuldade é apresentar os dados que estão no banco.

Estava tentando fazer assim:

```
$("#dias_semana").val(diasDaSemana[]);
```

Mas não funcionou.Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Você poderia esclarecer o que é o `diasDaSemana[]`? Em javascript isso não significa nada a não ser que seja uma variávei e o `[]` no final irá causar um erro. Eu poderia pensar que o seu objetivo seria selecionar o último item da array `diasDaSemana`, ou até mesmo pegar o elemento com o name=diasDaSemana. Poderia esclarecer, assim eu posso te ajudar melhor.

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira é uma variavel sim.... também não sei explicar, pois peguei isso da net e funcionou para salvar no banco... o problema está em pegar do banco e mostrar pro usuário oque foi salvo... por exemplo.... seleciono Domingo... ai na minha tela de edição... esse select option Domingo, teria que estar marcado. Aqui que estou camelando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja este código:

```
var diasDaSemana = ["Segunda", "Quarta", "Quinta"];//Deverá ser carregada do banco de dados

$.each(diasDaSemana, function(idx, val) {
  $('#dias_semana option[value=' + val + ']').attr('selected', true);
});
```

A váriavel `diasDaSemana` deverá ser carregada do banco de dados, posteriormente o `each` irá selecionar cada opção.

Comment: segui seu exemplo e não funcionou: https://jsfiddle.net/4yydLL5L/

Comment: resolvido. http://jsfiddle.net/McddQ/1/   obrigada pela explicação.

Comment: Fico feliz. Obrigado por escolher minha resposta. :D

Answer (score 0):

Um simples plugin para jQuery:

```
(function($, window) {
  $.fn.replaceOptions = function(options) {
    var self, $option;

    this.empty();
    self = this;

    $.each(options, function(index, option) {
      $option = $("<option></option>")
        .attr("value", option.value)
        .text(option.text);
      self.append($option);
    });
  };
})(jQuery, window);
```

Usa-se desta forma:

```
$("#foo").replaceOptions(options);
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16654226/5660495

Comment: Pelo que entendi, o usuário não perguntou como substituir as opções pelos valores de uma Array, mas sim selecionar no select os valores que vieram do banco de dados